# Add field to menu link content

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to add a list field to the menu links. I have executed the database update and it creates the field in the "menu_link_content_data" table correctly. But when I go to the menu link form the field does not appear. I have tried to clear cache, run the cron and even add the field by hand with an alter form. No value is ever saved in the database.

Even if I check the definition of the entity, the field I created does not appear

```
$defition = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('menu_link_content', 'bundle');
```

This is my hook update.

```
  // Installing a new field storage definition.
  $field_storage_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
    ->setLabel(t('Menu type'))
    ->setTranslatable(FALSE)
    ->setSettings([
      'allowed_values' => AreaMenu::getMenuTypes(),
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type'   => 'options_select',
      'weight' => 10,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

  Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
    ->installFieldStorageDefinition('menu_type_service', 'menu_link_content', 'menu_link_content', $field_storage_definition);
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug in the core, could someone give me some indication? Thank you very much.

**Drupal 8.9.1**

Comment: Given there is a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) that does exactly what you are doing, there surely is no bug in core.

Comment: Thank you for responding. You are right that this module is similar to what I need, but it is not valid for me because the fields are at the level of each menu. And I need that all the menus have that base field, even the new ones

Comment: Before you can run the update hook you need to add the field to 
[hook_entity_base_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info/9.0.x) first.

Comment: Then I need to define the field in the hook_update and in the hook_entity_base_field_info aswell? As I read here I understood that only the hook update was necessary since Drupal 8.7 :/

Comment: The crucial part is hook_entity_base_field_info, the update hook is only necessary if you want to add this field for already installed module instances.

Comment: I understand, I'll try it tomorrow and I'll let you know if it works for me, thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes, using the field in the update and in the hook info works. The field appears automatically and when I save the information is stored in the database. Thank you very much :)